# document ready vs using and not using on

Tags: jquery

This code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/J984N/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('called');
});
```

But why this code [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/J984N/):

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    alert('called');
});
```

Comment: because you are binding the ready event before the DOM ready

Comment: Side note: Unless you don't control where the `script` tags go, there's little reason to use `ready` vs. just putting your `script` tags at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), **deprecated as of jQuery 1.8**. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to .on( "ready" ) the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could *ever* use `ready` with `on` (I even double-checked the `on` docs just to be sure). +1

Answer (score 0):

[API Doc says](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to .on( "ready" ) the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this site it might help you understand why the second example doesn't work `http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/`